# prompt() in a loop never shows writeln() content

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am new to javascript, having trouble with this assignment. My professor suggested the problem was due to needing to parseInt, but even after I added the parseInt, it still isn't working.

This displays fine in Firefox, and the "higher" and "lower" statements are displayed, but when I run it in Chrome or Edge, only the window asking for a number will render. I did look for help, but I cant see what I'm doing wrong. Most of the suggestions Ive seen online, don't address the code directly. Is this problem specific code related or something else?

```js
function play() {

  let guess;
  let randNum = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 999);
  let guessed = false;

  while (guessed == false) {
    guess = window.prompt("Enter a number from 1 to 1000");
    parseInt(guess);
    if (guess == randNum) {
      document.writeln("<li>" + "Congratulations! You guessed the correct number!</li>");
      guessed = true;
      document.writeln("</ol>");
      document.writeln("Your guess: " + guess);
      document.writeln("Actual number: " + randNum);
    } else if (guess > randNum) {
      document.writeln("<li>" + guess + " is Too High. Try Again.</li>");
      document.writeln("</ol>");
    } else if (guess < randNum) {
      document.writeln("<li>" + guess + " is Too Low. Try Again.</li>");
      document.writeln("</ol>");
    }
  }

}

window.addEventListener("load", play, false);
```

Comment: This is not the source of the problem, but I thought I'd mention it anyway. `parseInt` [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#return_value) an integer value, so you might consider `guess = parseInt(guess);`

Comment: [Don't use `document.writeln`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice). Use `alert()` instead, until you learn about the DOM and asynchronous event handling (and don't need to use `prompt` any longer).

Comment: ***"Only works in Firefox"* cannot be a Question title**. Imagine all questions here were like *"Does not work in Chrome"* - you wouldn't be able to google a thing. Please [edit].

Comment: `document.writeln` is just not the way to go. You should only append LI elements to an OL element already present in the DOM. Learn about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does alert appear before background changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945552/why-does-alert-appear-before-background-changes) - essentially Firefox doesn't block rendering during an `alert` and other browsers do.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  "Firefox" is a useful keyword when looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: @traktor The question **title** was changed in the meantime. I was not talking about the *Firefox* **Tag**. The question title was exactly like I stated above. If in doubt, see the  [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71632053/revisions) .

Answer (score 2):

- Don't use `writeln`. Use the proper methods like [.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) or [.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) or [.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) if you just want to insert HTML strings instead of Nodes.
- Don't use `alert`, `prompt`, etc. Those Window methods will most likely get deprecated or at least discouraged in the near future.
- Remember, use `let` for variables, and `const` for constants.
- Use DOM methods like [Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get and store a DOM [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element),
- Use [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)  to create a new one (a new LI Element in your case)

To ease the querying or creation of the desired DOM Elements — create two reusable functions:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const find   = (selector, parent) => (parent || document).querySelector(selector);
const create = (tag, properties) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), properties);
```

that can be used to cache your Elements and use them later in your game logic

```js
// Cache your DOM elements!
const elNumber  = find("#number"); 
const elCheck   = find("#check");
const elAnswers = find("#answers");
```

which will target and cache your three HTML elements by theri `id` attribute selector. As said above, instead of using `prompt`, use a better and less invasive UI (User interface) right into your App:

```html
Enter a number from 1 to 10: <input id="number" type="text">
<button id="check" type="button">CHECK</button>
<ol id="answers"></ol>
```

Then create two `let` variables for the guessed state and one for the random number, so that when you start a new game you can change their values:

```js
// Make available for multiple games!
let numRand;
let isGuessed;
```

then, giving your specific game, you need two more functions, one to start (and restart) the game and one for your game logic:

```js
// Call this function to start a new game!
const start = () => {
  // Clear old answers
  // Reset old guessed state
  // Generate a new random number
};

// Call this function on button CHECK click!
const check = () => {
  // Game logic goes here!
}

// Assign listener to button:
elCheck.addEventListener("click", check);

// Start a new game!
start();
```

### Demo time:

```js
// DOM utility functions:

const find   = (selector, parent) => (parent || document).querySelector(selector);
const create = (tag, properties) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), properties);

// Task:

// Cache your DOM elements!
const elNumber  = find("#number"); // PS: remember, use const for constants!
const elCheck   = find("#check");
const elAnswers = find("#answers");

// Make available for multiple games!
let numRand;
let isGuessed; // Try to prefix boolean variables with "is*"


// Call this function to start a new game!
const start = () => {
  // Clear old answers:
  elAnswers.innerHTML = "";

  // Reset old guessed state
  isGuessed = false;

  // Generate a new random number 1 to 10:
  numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
};


// Call this function on button CHECK click!
const check = () => {

  // Start a new game if needed
  if (isGuessed) start();

  // Get the user entered value
  // Use parseInt with radix 10 and Math.abs
  // to prevent negative numbers
  const numUser = Math.abs(parseInt(elNumber.value, 10)); 

  // Do nothing if invalid value entered:
  if (!numUser) return;

  // Update isGuessed state
  isGuessed = numRand === numUser;

  // Handle answer:
  const textAnswer = `
    You guessed: ${numUser}.
    The number is ${isGuessed ? "correct!" : numUser > numRand ? "too high." : "too low."}
    ${isGuessed ? "Congratulations!" : "Try again"}
  `;

  // Create a LI element with the answer text
  const elAnswer = create("li", {
    textContent: textAnswer
  });

  // Append your LI element!
  elAnswers.append(elAnswer);

  // Clear the current value from input:
  elNumber.value = "";
};


// Assign listener to button:
elCheck.addEventListener("click", check);

// Start a new game!
start();
```

```html
Enter a number from 1 to 10: <input id="number" type="text">
<button id="check" type="button">CHECK</button>
<ol id="answers"></ol>
```

Additional learning resources:

- [Arrow_functions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Template literals /Template strings (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Conditional (ternary) operator (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: If we're following best practices, let's also follow the JS naming conventions =) (`numRand`, rather than python `num_rand`, `find()` instead of `EL()`, `create()` instead of `ELnew()`, just spelling out `parent` instead of `par` since the engine doesn't care but humans do, etc)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes I agree 100%, amazing suggestion. Adopted.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, JavaScript is single-threaded, meaning that it has only [one execution thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718820/924299). Methods like `prompt()` and `alert()` [block that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49646023/924299). As long as `prompt()` is called in a loop, `writeln` content will not be rendered on the page.

One way to address this with your existing code is to use `setTimeout()` to delay the next call to `prompt()`, which allows content to be rendered in the meantime.

That being said, I recommend a more asynchronous method that does not rely on `prompt()` or `writeln()`. This answer is intended to explain the issue with your existing code; for a more robust strategy, see [Roko's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71632780/924299).

```js
var randNum = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 999);

function ask() {
  let guess = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number from 1 to 1000"));
  if (guess == randNum) {
    document.writeln("<div>Congratulations! You guessed the correct number!</div>");
    document.writeln("<div>Your guess: " + guess + ". Actual number: " + randNum + "</div>");
  } else if (guess > randNum) {
    document.writeln("<div>" + guess + " is Too High. Try Again.</div>");
    setTimeout(ask, 50);
  } else if (guess < randNum) {
    document.writeln("<div>" + guess + " is Too Low. Try Again.</div>");
    setTimeout(ask, 50);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", ask, false);
```

Comment: But if we're giving an answer, we might as well remove all that `document.writeln` and replace it with proper JS, because _especially_ people new to JS should _never_ use document.write(ln) and should be taught what to use instead (in this case, ye olde document.createElement, .textContent, and appendChild)

Comment: Good point! I encourage you to write such an answer, including explanation of *why* to avoid certain code. Also note that `appendChild()` on its own may not solve the problem, because `prompt()` will still block the thread.